# Get 'XXX' value using a RegEx in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need some help building a regex for get the value of `XXX` in the following set of possible matches:

```
+58XXXYYYYYYY
+580XXXYYYYYYY
0XXXYYYYYYY
XXXYYYYYYY
```

This are phone numbers so `XXX` is dynamic and will not hold always the same value. The RegEx is intended to be used on PHP so I know I should use `preg_match()` function but I have not idea about the regex. Can any give me some advice on this?

Comment: `XXX` are the last `y` numbers ?

Comment: @Thomas no, it will have more 7 numbers after `XXX`, see my update!

Comment: Why the down vote and the vote for closing?

Comment: It sounds like *someone* find your question too broad

Comment: @Thomas I think that SO should penalize this kind of people which doesn't add nothing helpful and just make two clicks for say our question is bad :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it matches your requirements:

```
(\d{3})\d{7}$
```

With a <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qJ0yT8/1)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

If you want to match the last 3 numbers, you could use `/([0-9]{3,3})$/`.

The parenthesis indicates a capturing group (what you are looking for). Inside that group you want to match a pattern `[...]`of any number `0-9` exactly 3 times `{3,3}`. And finally you want to match the last occurrence of this pattern, so the `$` indicates the end of the line.

A very handy tool to building simple regex queries is [Debuggex](http://debuggex.com). I use it all the time!